Ошибка 422 requests python
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PTdUmkT-yas на 42:22 он посылает запрос, и все срабатывает
я делаю тоже самое и получаю код 422.
import requests
import time

t = round(time.time()) - 3
url = "https://api.hamsterkombatgame.io/clicker/tap"
data = {"count":1500,"availableTaps":0,"timestamp":t}
headers = [
            {
              "name": "authorization",
              "value": "авторизация"
            },
            {
              "name": "user-agent",
              "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
            }]
real_headers = {}
for i in headers:
    real_headers[i["name"]] = i["value"]
print(real_headers)
a = requests.post(data=data, headers=real_headers, url=url)

P.S если что через postman я тоже пробовал

Этому видео уже почти два месяца, вполне логично предположить, что за это время в хомяке успело поменяться примерно всё, возможно даже специально для защиты от таких шибко хитрых как вы)

Мат здесь не приветствуется

Через постман у меня все работает:
curl --location 'https://api.hamsterkombatgame.io/clicker/tap' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer 17....твой токен' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7' \
--header 'Origin: https://hamsterkombatgame.io' \
--data '{
    "count": 1000,
    "availableTaps": 0,
    "timestamp": {{currentTimestamp}}
}
'

где currentTimestamp - это Pre-request Script:
// Get the current Unix timestamp in seconds
const timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
// Set the timestamp as an environment variable
pm.environment.set("currentTimestamp", timestamp);


спасибо, работает!
